# how to route if users from (10.70.100.0/24) want to use IPPBX then it would use the eth1?

Tags: centos-7

I run CentOS 7, my ifconfig as follow:

eth0 serves LAN users, and eth1 is the IPPBX, how to route if users from (10.70.100.0/24) want to use IPPBX then it would use the eth1?

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.70.100.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.70.100.255
        inet6 fe80::4f57:e7c0:4e6a:6c2a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:6b:8d:a6:58:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 588935  bytes 43189679 (41.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2779  bytes 218333 (213.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.89.79.155  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast 10.89.79.159
        inet6 fe80::333d:b66a:ff:374d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:6b:8d:98:59:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 404739  bytes 103605341 (98.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 296377  bytes 90577054 (86.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3249746256  bytes 418008338437 (389.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3249746256  bytes 418008338437 (389.3 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

nmap eth0:

PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql


eth1:
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2024-01-18 11:31 UTC
Nmap scan report for 10.89.79.155
Host is up (0.00053s latency).
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
5060/tcp open  sip
5061/tcp open  sip-tls
```

Comment: You can set up a route on each host in the 10.70.100.0/24 subnet for the 10.89.79.152/29 subnet. Or you install a routing protocol such as OSPF on the network devices to handle routing. Or you you insert a route on the 10.70.100.0/24 default gateway for that subnet & hope that redirection works.